# Login Item - cocoa

Tags: swift, cocoa

Is there a way to check if the login item already exists (with bundleIdentifier of the app?) I want to be able to see if there is a login item and if it is enable.
I was trying to check my checkbox in applicationDidFinishLuanching when the login item is enabled using this:

```
if (SMLoginItemSetEnabled(("bundleIDOfMyApp" as CFStringRef), true)) {
        self.startAtLoginButton.state = 1
    } else {
        self.startAtLoginButton.state = 0
    }
```

It does its thing, but it also launches my helper application.

Another thing is this:

```
@IBAction func startAtLoginButtonChecked(sender: NSButton) {
    var enabled = false
    if sender.state == 0 { enabled = false }
    if sender.state == 1 { enabled = true }
    if !SMLoginItemSetEnabled(("bundleIDOfMyApp" as CFStringRef), enabled) {
        print("Login was not successful")
    }
}
```

As far as I am concerned this is the way you implement checkbox to enable/disable login item.

What it does in my app is every time I check the box it launches the helper app (which launches my app again).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although the method `SMCopyAllJobDictionaries()` is deprecated this is the usual way to check if the job is enabled, `SMLoginItemSetEnabled` is only be used to set the value

```
import ServiceManagement

let jobDicts = SMCopyAllJobDictionaries( kSMDomainUserLaunchd ).takeRetainedValue() as NSArray as! [[String:AnyObject]]
let label =  "bundleIDOfMyApp"
let jobEnabled = jobDicts.filter { $0["Label"] as! String == label }.isEmpty == false
```

The double casting is needed to cast `CFArray` to `NSArray` and then to  `Array<String,AnyObject>`

---

Also usually the checkbox is bound to a property via KVC. The lines above are the getter and `SMLoginItemSetEnabled` is the setter for example

```
let helperBundleIdentifier = "bundleIDOfMyApp" 

@available(OSX, deprecated=10.10) // this line suppresses the 'deprecated' warning
dynamic var startAtLogin : Bool {
  get {
    guard let jobDicts = SMCopyAllJobDictionaries( kSMDomainUserLaunchd ).takeRetainedValue() as NSArray as? [[String:AnyObject]] else { return false }
    return jobDicts.filter { $0["Label"] as! String == helperBundleIdentifier }.isEmpty == false
  } set {
    if !SMLoginItemSetEnabled(helperBundleIdentifier, newValue) {
      print("SMLoginItemSetEnabled failed.")
    }
  }
}
```

**Swift 3:**

```
@available(OSX, deprecated: 10.10)
dynamic var startAtLogin : Bool {
  get {
    guard let jobDicts = SMCopyAllJobDictionaries( kSMDomainUserLaunchd ).takeRetainedValue() as? [[String:Any]] else { return false }
    return jobDicts.first(where: { $0["Label"] as! String == helperBundleIdentifier }) != nil
  } set {
    if !SMLoginItemSetEnabled(helperBundleIdentifier as CFString, newValue) {
      print("SMLoginItemSetEnabled failed.")
    }
  }
}
```

Side note: A launchd job requires the key `Label` so it's 100% safe to unwrap the optional in the `filter` function.

Comment: Uoou! That is pretty advanced. I hope it will help a lot of people. Thanks a lot for that!

Comment: I implemented your code in my project, but I still have one problem. When I set startAtLogin using my checkbox it launches my helper app, which launches my main app.

Comment: The code is straightforward, you might have a design problem integrating the helper app

Comment: @Ancinek I too am experiencing the same behavior. Did you manage to implement this?

Comment: I found this useful background on the deprecated call: https://github.com/feedback-assistant/reports/issues/16